# .load() now loading live data into the div in IE9 works fine in FF and chrome

Tags: jquery

After adding a new data I am reloading the div with new data. IT works fine in FF and chrome but it load crap data in IE9.

```
$('#tabledata').load('load.php');
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the "crap data"

Comment: @Abhinab: if it loads crap you should try to wipe it first :)

Comment: The same problem is arising with me, the data is not displayed in the grid of the page for IE9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer returns the data from cache

Try

```
$.ajaxSetup{
     cache: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once.

Try adding a timestamp as a parametrer you send, or something that changes each time you send a `load` request. I don't know the reason but it happens that in IE doesn't really makes the new load, it takes it like is the same load that it was made before, so he took it like a HTTP Response `304: Not Modified` and you obtain the same as in the first load.